# print('>>>') results in a blank line?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I am using Pycharm and trying to print text to the console

```
print('>')
>
print('>>')
>>
print('>>>')
```

The final print command ('>>>') prints a blank line. Why is that? How can I print out the three >'s?

Comment: That'd be a PyCharm issue, if true.

Comment: I guess PyCharm uses the built-in REPL and trims `>>>`. Not sure why it would bother, since it’s a useful prompt. Report it as a PyCharm bug.

Comment: I reported it to Pycharm as a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DTRC-24836

Answer (score 0):

If you can tolerate the space, you can do:

`print(" >>>")`